# Wacom Intous Art Support on Ubuntu 15.10 wily

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, kubuntu, wacom

Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.2.0-36-generic

OS: Ubuntu 15.10 wily

DE: KDE5

So I have followed several articles online from several google searches such as: 
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=110304
http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Downloads (Where I first went, didn't get past getting Wacom-input to work)

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu and I would really like to use my **Wacom Intous Art** (medium) drawing tablet  with my Ubuntu OS, but I don't really know what to do or how to fix this. Any help would be really appreciated.

My kernel is recognizing the Wacom tablet it seems,
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 056a:033e Wacom Co., Ltd 
is what `lsusb` says, so I think I just need to find a software that will use it that is compatible with my kernel ? I am not really sure what to do from here.